# Eclipse compilation error for generic method

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-errors

I'm getting a compilation error in Eclipse, while using a generic method, which doesn't appear when using javac. I'm guessing it's a compiler option in Eclipse, but I can't see a relevant item in the Preferences window.

The example I'm working with is from Thinking In Java 4th Edition, the relevant code is below, copied and pasted from the downloadable examples from the book's website.

```
//: generics/Generators.java
// A utility to use with Generators.
import java.util.*;
import net.mindview.util.*;

public class Generators {
  public static <T> Collection<T>
  fill(Collection<T> coll, Generator<T> gen, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      coll.add(gen.next());
    return coll;
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Coffee> coffee = fill(
      new ArrayList<Coffee>(), new CoffeeGenerator(), 4);
    for(Coffee c : coffee)
      System.out.println(c);  }
}
```

`Generator`, `Coffee` and `CoffeeGenerator` are defined elsewhere, but I don't believe they are relevant to my issue.

This code gives me the compiler error: 'The method fill(Collection, Generator, int) in the type Generators is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, CoffeeGenerator, int)'.

Any ideas which option I can change to make Eclipse compile the same as when I use javac from the command line?

Many thanks in advance! I did do a search (here and Google) and couldn't find an answer - apologies if this is a repeat.

Code for CoffeeGenerator:

```
//: generics/coffee/CoffeeGenerator.java
// Generate different types of Coffee:
import java.util.*;
import net.mindview.util.*;

public class CoffeeGenerator
implements Generator<Coffee>, Iterable<Coffee> {
  private Class[] types = { Latte.class, Mocha.class,
    Cappuccino.class, Americano.class, Breve.class, };
  private static Random rand = new Random(47);
  public CoffeeGenerator() {}
  // For iteration:
  private int size = 0;
  public CoffeeGenerator(int sz) { size = sz; } 
  public Coffee next() {
    try {
      return (Coffee)
        types[rand.nextInt(types.length)].newInstance();
      // Report programmer errors at run time:
    } catch(Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
  class CoffeeIterator implements Iterator<Coffee> {
    int count = size;
    public boolean hasNext() { return count > 0; }
    public Coffee next() {
      count--;
      return CoffeeGenerator.this.next();
    }
    public void remove() { // Not implemented
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  };    
  public Iterator<Coffee> iterator() {
    return new CoffeeIterator();
  }
}
```

Code for Generator:

```
//: net/mindview/util/Generator.java
// A generic interface.
package net.mindview.util;
public interface Generator<T> { T next(); } ///:~
```

Comment: So how does CoffeeGenerator extend or implement Generator.Does it use Coffee as type parameter while extending/implemening  Generator

Comment: CoffeeGenerator implements Generator<Coffee> - I'll add the code for it to my question.

Comment: BigMatt Please paste the code of Generator.Also,specify if Generator is class or interface

Comment: Added the code for interface Generator.

Comment: It compiles fine for me.

Comment: @BigMatt What is fill(), exactly?

Comment: It compiles fine for me using javac on the command line. It doesn't compile in Eclipse, though, as per the description above. This is what makes me think it's a generics-related compiler option in Eclipse. Eclipse suggests fixing the error by de-generifying the type of the first parameter of fill.